# valueChanges reactive form in Array especific field

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

What is the correct way to subscribe to changes within a field of an Array that is in a reactive form?

What I want is to show / hide a field depending on the selection of the `tipo` field the problem is that these fields are part of an Array and it only works on the first element.

[image]
[image]

How can I make it work correctly every time I want to add a group to the array?

**components.ts**

```
tipoTelefono = ['Celular', 'Teléfono fijo'];
telefonoSeleccionado = 'Celular';
phones = [];

this.formAviso = this.fb.group ({
  titulo: [ '', Validators.required ],
  telefonos: this.fb.array([
    this.fb.group({
       tipo: [this.telefonoSeleccionado],
       numero: ['']
    })
  ])
});
 this.formAviso.get('telefonos').valueChanges.subscribe( res => {
  this.phones = res;
  for (const phone of this.phones) {
    this.telefonoSeleccionado = phone.tipo;
    console.log( this.telefonoSeleccionado);
  }
});

agregarTelefono() {
(this.formAviso.controls['telefonos'] as FormArray).push(
  this.fb.group({
    tipo: ['Celular'],
    numero: ['']
    })
  );
}
```

**component.html**

```
<div formArrayName="telefonos" class="col-12">
  <div *ngFor="let telefono of formAviso.controls['telefonos']['controls']; let i = index;">
    <div class="d-flex" [formGroupName]="i">
      <div class="row w-100">

      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Tipo</mat-label>
        <mat-select formControlName="tipo">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let tipo of tipoTelefono;" [value]="tipo">{{tipo}}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>

      </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="col-6 col-md-4" *ngIf="telefonoSeleccionado === 'Teléfono fijo'">
        <mat-label>Código ciudad</mat-label>
        <input matInput formArrayName="numero">
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="col-6 col-md-4">
        <mat-label>Número</mat-label>
        <input matInput formArrayName="numero">
      </mat-form-field>

      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 d-flex align-items-center" *ngIf="telefonoSeleccionado === 'Celular'">
        <mat-checkbox>WhatsApp</mat-checkbox>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button (click)="agregarTelefono()">Agregar Teléfono</button>
 </div>
```